# How to trigger a function if ANY link is clicked, by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm a jQuery newbie and I've spent hours trying to find the answer to this and the documentations didn't help me much.

I simply want to change the style of:

```
#footer_menu{bottom:0;}
```

to

```
#footer_menu{bottom:-48px;}
```

once ANY link on the page is clicked. No IDs whatsoever, I just want to be able to trigger that function whenever ANY link is clicked.

I'm starting to wonder this is not at all possible and it should be done by adding IDs to the A tags. is this true and what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#footer_menu').css('bottom', '-48px');
    event.preventDefault(); // only if links should not navigate afterwards
});
```

You just basically select all anchors with `$('a')`.

Comment: I ended up doing something else to fix what I wanted, but this helped eliminate the fact that I thought this method was going to work.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this, [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rscEB/2/)

```
$('a').click(function() {      
   $('#footer_menu').css('bottom', '-48px');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
     $('#footer_menu').css('bottom', '-48px');
     e.preventDefault();
}
```